# Why is there an error in myJson structure?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to correct my json but I still have some errors, I did use a Json Editor but it didn't help me to understand what is the error 
I don't know if it has a one more open '{' in my code or does it miss a ',' ?
It seems the error is on line 79 but I don't know exactly what is not correct exactly..

```
   {
      "data": [{
          "Contact_Name": {
              "id": "1884053000034678068"
          },
          "Subject": "1 - XKBKNABJK",
          "Status": "Sans Impact Stock",
          "Entity": "",
          "Etat": "CM - Annul\u00e9",
          "Invoice_Date": "2017-11-21",
          "Discount": 0.000000,
          "Tax": ["TVA"],
          "Total_HT": "55.000000",
          "Total_TVA": 0,
          "Methode_de_paiement": "Payment by check",
          "ID_Lip": "1",
          "Origine": "CM",
          "Type_de_Facture": "Solde",
          "Transporteur": "My carrier",
          "Reference_Colis": "",
          "Billing_Street": "16, Main street",
          "Compl_ment_Facturation": "2nd floor",
          "Billing_City": "Miami",
          "Billing_Country": "\u00c9tats-Unis",
          "Billing_Code": "33133",
          "Shipping_Street": "16, Main street",
          "Compl_ment_Livraison": "2nd floor",
          "Shipping_City": "Miami",
          "Shipping_Country": "\u00c9tats-Unis",
          "Shipping_Code": "33133",
          "Product_Details": [{
              "product": {
                  "id": "1884053000030235273"
              },
              "Product_Name": "Blouse - Color : White, Size : M",
              "list_price": 22.5,
              "quantity": 1,
              "Discount": 0,
              "Discount_Amount": 0,
              "line_tax": [{
                  "percentage": 20,
                  "name": "TVA"
              }]
          }, {
              "product": {
                  "id": "1884053000030235273"
              },
              "Product_Name": "Printed Dress - Color : Orange, Size : S",
              "list_price": 21.67,
              "quantity": 1,
              "Discount": 0,
              "Discount_Amount": 0,
              "line_tax": [{
                  "percentage": 20,
                  "name": "TVA"
              }]
          }, {
              "product": {
                  "id": "1884053000012868763"
              },
              "list_price": 1.67,
              "quantity": 1,
              "Discount": 0,
              "Discount_Amount": 0,
              "line_tax": [{
                  "percentage": 20,
                  "name": "TVA"
              }]
          }],
          "Adjustment": 0,
          "Montant_TPH": 0,
          "TVA_sur_DEEE_TPH": "0",
          "Taxes_DEEE_TPH": "TPH",
          "Frais_de_port_HT": "2.000000",
          "Frais_de_port_TTC": "2.000000",
          "Nb_produits": 3,
          "Quantite_totale": 3
      }]
   }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is the error? We just talking about some IDE choking? Use something like [JSON lint](https://jsonlint.com/), or code. FWIW: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd5e933472ec31f446f6cce30b4b523e5881e7dc I see it as valid JSON.

Comment: If you are hand crafting the JSON then this can be the result.  Build the data in PHP and then `json_encode()` it.

Comment: That JSON is definitely okay and valid. You should explain further where and how are you using it and that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: It's when I use the function json_decode with the json text, it returns me nothing so I thought my json was uncorrect

Comment: Maybe show the whole code.